# Different resolutions on Android game

Tags: android, screen-resolution

how can I develop a game for different screen resolutions?
I have already read about Density independant pixels (dp), but I still don't know how to use them.
For example, what size should my View have in order to be fully displayed in every device?
Can I just set it to 1280dp x 800dp and start drawing things on my canvas related to this size?

Answer (score 0):

No, since the devices not only have different density, but also different ratios.

The easiest way is to decide your ratio (1,667 is the most popular) and create a canvas of that size. Then linearly scale the height(or the width) to match the device's one, and put black rectangles on the borders. It will work without borders in a big majority of the devices, and it will still look right on the others. This way you have the big advantage of always knowing the relative distance between your objects.

Btw i suggest you to use a graphic engine that handles it for you (for example andengine)

Comment: So if I create a canvas with a 8/5 ratio it will automatically adjust to the device's resolution?
For example I create a 1280dp x 800dp canvas, will it display properly on a 800x480 device?

Comment: @Ivan I didn't say that! I said that it is easier to decide a ratio and then scale the whole canvas to fit the display size than placing everything relatively to the dimension of the screen.
If you meant "In andengine, so if i...", then yes, it does it automatically

Comment: I will probably use AndEngine then, I didn't want to use it at first because this is my first game and I wanted to learn the basics.

Comment: @Ivan I hope you don't know what you are talking about, otherwise you must have a lot of free time (or paid time for learning). If you want to implement a "not so basic" game you should first learn all the openGL stuff, than implement all your graphic and game engine(if you want something that will be reusable), and then write your game. It is not such big problem for someone that already is familiar with openGL and game programming, but for someone who never wrote this kind of thing is a long trip,  and you don't see results until you have quite finished everything. Btw it is your choice.. gl